# regex that replace any chars (except number/, .)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string. I need to parse it, replacing any chars (except numbers (`0` to `9`),`,` and `.`.

How can I do it with javascript?

Tried with :

```
string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]*/, "");
```

but seems it doesnt works. Also, I need ANY chars, not only a-Z (also ?, /, white space, and so on, expect, as said, **,** and **.**

Comment: Create a negated character class: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. Don't forget the `g`lobal modifier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
[^0-9,.]
```

and put in any character you don't want to be replaced, it will match all the others.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?300b5)

You can optimize it by adding a quantifier `+`, so that it replaces a sequence of those characters at once and not each by each.

```
string.replace(/[^0-9,.]+/g, "");
```

As Felix Kling pointed out, its important to use the global option `g` to match on all occurrences of the pattern.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?300b8)

Comment: Don't forget the `g`lobal modifier.

Answer (score 7):

```
string.replace(/[^\d,.]+/g, "");
```

should do.

1. `[^\d.,]` means "any character except digit, comma or period", a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
2. Use `+` instead of `*` or you'll have lots of empty matches replaced with empty strings.
3. Use `/g` so all instances are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace all chars except digits and `.` `,` and do the replace globally:

```
string.replace(/[^0-9\,\.]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
Below code is prevent alpha key

```
onKeypress="return Custom(event,'[0-9]');"

function Custom(e, cPattern) {
    var key = [e.keyCode || e.which];
    var pattern = new String(cPattern);
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode([e.keyCode || e.which]);
    var pattern1 = new RegExp(pattern);

    if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) ||
                        (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (pattern1.test(keychar)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```