# if input field is not a number OR not empty replace with a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input, replace

I have an input field that I am monitoring for changes using an .on('input') function as this covers .change and .keyup.

There is no submit button yet I just want to change the behaviour of the input field depending on what is entered.

I will validate server side later and I'm using html5 type='number'.

I only want the field to be able to hold a number, or it can be empty. The user might want to empty the contents to type the number 15 for example.

However I don't want any other characters to be accepted - if they are entered, a prompt should show notifying the user of this and the field is defaulted back to it's starting value of 1.

HTML

```
<input type="number" class="input-field" placeholder="" value="1" min="1">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    var num = $('input[type="number"]').val();

    $('input[type="number"]').on('input', function () {
        var num = $(this).val();

        if (num < 1 || isNaN(num) || num !== '') {
            alert(num + ' is not a number or is less than 1');
            $(this).val(1);
        }

    });
});
```

I have tried with the above code and it doesn't allow for an empty field. I've also tried `if (num < 1 || isNAN(num) || num.length != 0) {`

do I need to use `.replace()` with a Regexr. I've been looking at a few questions on here like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261822/regex-that-replace-any-chars-expect-number) but I'm not sure thats what I'm looking for considering I'm testing for an empty string.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xLrd6jnm/3/)

Comment: `isNAN` should be `isNaN`

Comment: I would simply force the value to be within your parameters. I will post an answer in a moment.

Comment: @VenkataPanga thx have updated question but still fails

Comment: `this.validity.valid` is enough to check html5 element valid type chekcing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [constraint validation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api):

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('input', function () {
    if (!this.validity.valid) {
        alert(this.value + ' is not a number or is less than 1');
        this.value = 1;
    }    
});
```

```js
$('input[type="number"]').on('input', function () {
    if (!this.validity.valid) {
        alert(this.value + ' is not a number or is less than 1');
        this.value = 1;
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="input-field" placeholder="" value="1" min="1">
```

However, note that this behavior is obtrusive. If an user types the wrong key, you will annoy him with a modal dialog and will clear the number.

Consider doing nothing. HTML5 browsers won't send the form if the input is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 answer is definitely more elegant.

But if you want to offer more support, this is usually the route I take when trying to verify numbers.

Note that I am using `data-min` attribute but if you want to switch you can always use `$.attr()` to grab your `min=""` attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('input[type="number"]').on('change', function () {
        var min = parseInt(this.dataset.min),
            num = isNaN(parseInt(this.value)) ? 0 : parseInt(this.value),
            clamped = Math.max(num, min);

        if(num != clamped) {
            alert(num + ' is less than 1');
            this.value = clamped;
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evilzebra/xLrd6jnm/7/)